# Lightning Network: what if one broadcast an old transaction?

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, blockchain, lightning-network

I understand that after a channel is created, A and B need to agree and sign to create a new transaction. The new transaction overrides the previous transaction. A or B could quit the channel by broadcasting the transaction onto Bitcoin network so that the transaction is final:

```
txn 0: A:0.5, B:0.5
txn 1: A:0.3, B:0.7
txn 2: A:0.9, B:0.1
```

A or B quit channel, broadcast `txn 2`, so A will have 0.9 and B will have 0.1

But what if B quit the channel, broadcasting `txn 1` rather than `txn 2` on to the Bitcoin network? Wouldn't the `txn 1` becomes final and B could walk away with 0.7?

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! I can see you have some experience on SE sites so I will leave you to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is a time until which A can question the transaction because he will have proof for the later transaction that has happened. And B will lose all the money in the channel for broadcasting a previous transaction.

Comment: If B already send all money to A, wouldn't B not lost anything by trying so, camping on the possibility that A could be offline on that period of time? (btw, how long is the period? It probably is not too long, because the BTC is probably locked in the period)